# how to access set elements by index?

Tags: python, set

I was working on recommendation system (RS) in python when I came across a serious problem: I couldn't access the set without changing its order.

e.g. Once I changed a set to list the order gets change. (In recommendation, system order is very important.)

`final_prediction=set(df_final)-set(df1)`

e.g.

```
>>> df_final=['a','x','z','p','s','j','b']
>>> df1=['b','j']
>>> set(df_final)-set(df1)
{'p', 'a', 's', 'z', 'x'}
```

Here `df_final` and `df1` both are categorical variables

Although I used other approach, I had to scratch my butt's to change the code because it was giving perfect results using set thing and all other things were just working fine. I was in the final phase of my RS, but because of the set order I had to take other approach.

How do we access an set without changing the order?

Comment: As soon as you have a `set` you don't get order... can't you just remove values from `df_final` if they're in `df1` and keep it a list?

Comment: _in recommendation system order is very important_ Then perhaps you should not use a set, as sets are inherently unordered.

Answer (score 5):

`set` is an unordered collection. For an ordered collection, you can use `list` or `tuple`. You now have a few options. Your choice should depend on whether you expect repeats in `df_final`. If you have no repeats, you can use a list comprehension:

```
df1_set = set(df1)
res1 = [i for i in df_final if i not in df1_set]
# ['a', 'x', 'z', 'p', 's']
```

If you have repeats in `df_final`, then you need unique items with ordering maintained. For this, you can use `toolz.unique`, which is equivalent to the `unique_everseen` recipe found in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from toolz import unique

res2 = [i for i in unique(df_final) if i not in df1_set]
```

Comment: It's a little bit of a cheat which I'm sure some will love in chat :p, but since you're making `df1_set` - you can also mutate that to store elements to also not use again (eg: the duplicated entries after)... so you end up with `[el for el in df_final if el not in df1_set and df1_set.add(el) is None]`... but deduplicating the input list is easier to grok...

Comment: You can also (ab)use an OrderedDict to do the dedupe... `[el for el in OrderedDict.fromkeys(df_final) if el not in df1_set]` instead of a 3rd party library (although some of the recipes in the itertools documentation are also v. useful)

Comment: @JonClements, Yes, I've seen that `OrderedDict.fromkeys` trick a few times. It certainly works, but I'm reluctant to recommend it as it seems a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need ordered sets, I recommend using the ActiveState [recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html?highlight=orderedset) recommends in the "**See also:**" at the very end.

If you put the recipe's code in a separate file named `orderedset.py`, it can be `import`ed as a module and used like this:

```
from orderedset import OrderedSet  # See https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694

df_final = ['a','x','z','p','s','j','b']
df1 = ['b','j']
print(OrderedSet(df_final) - OrderedSet(df1))  # -> OrderedSet(['a', 'x', 'z', 'p', 's'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The lists, the first one is ordered

```
>>> df_final=['a','x','z','p','s','j','b']
>>> df1=['b','j']
```

This works but it's O(N×M)

```
>>> [cat_var for cat_var in df_final if cat_var not in df1]
['a', 'x', 'z', 'p', 's']
```

This has a setup cost but it's O(N), if both lists are long...

```
>>> sdf1 = set(df1)
>>> [cat_var for cat_var in df_final if cat_var not in sdf1]
['a', 'x', 'z', 'p', 's']
```